# Connect SQL Server on button click VB.net

Tags: sql-server, vb.net, connection-string

How to connect SQL Server on button click?
I want to manually enter the Server, Username and Password into textboxes.

I have a code here but I'm not sure if it's correct.

```
Private Sub SQLConnect_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles SQLConnect.Click
    Dim con As SqlConnection = New SqlConnection("Server=" & SQLServer.Text & ";Database=GameDB;User Id=" & SQLUser.Text & ";Password=" & SQLPwd.Text & ";")
    con.Open()
        MsgBox("Successfully Connected!")
    'con.Close()
End Sub
```

Idk how to check if the connection is correct or not. If the input is right or wrong.
Please give me full code example. Thank you!

Comment: The param name should be `Password`, not `Pwd`

Comment: why would you give the server password to the user...ever?

Comment: @Plutonix what are you talking about? I'm gonna ask the user for server password to use my app.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Imports System.Data.SqlClient
Public Class Form1
Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Dim connetionString As String
    Dim cnn As SqlConnection
    connetionString = "Data Source=ServerName;Initial Catalog=DatabaseName;User ID=UserName;Password=Password"
    cnn = New SqlConnection(connetionString)
    Try
        cnn.Open()
        MsgBox("Connection Open ! ")
        cnn.Close()
    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox("Can not open connection ! ")
    End Try
End Sub
End Class
```

Answer (score 1):

```
Dim builder As New SqlConnectionStringBuilder()
builder.DataSource = SQLServer.Text
builder.InitialCatalog = "GameDB"
builder.UserID = SQLUser.Text
builder.Password = SQLPwd.Text
builder.ApplicationName = "MyGame"

Using connection As New SqlConnection(builder.ConnectionString)
   Try
       connection.Open()
       MsgBox("Connection can be opened")
   Catch ex As Exception
       MsgBox("Connection can not be opened: " & vbCrLf & ex)
   End Try
End Using
```

Comment: I tried using this code but it says, "'builder' is not declared"