# Connect SQL Server with VB.net on button click

Tags: sql-server, vb.net

Im still new in `vb` and would like to create a form that manually enter username and pssword in textbox and choose server and database in combobox. I did refer to this link [testconnection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33090524/connect-sql-server-on-button-click-vb-net) but i dont want to set the connection string and I want to test the connection after I manually enter the server, database, username n password. Here is the error that Im getting even though I put the correct data [After button test is clicked](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kg5u8.png) Is there any wrong in my coding?
`

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Dim connectString1 As String
    Dim cnn As SqlConnection

    server = Me.cmbServers.Text
    database = Me.cmbDatabases.Text
    username = Me.TextBoxUsername.Text
    password = Me.TextBoxPassword.Text

    'Set connection string with selected server and integrated security

    connectString1 = "Data Source=" & cmbServers.Text & ";Initial Catalog=" & cmbDatabases.Text & ";User ID=" & TextBoxUsername.Text & ";Password=" & TextBoxPassword.Text & " Integrated Security=True"

    cnn = New SqlConnection(connectString1)
    Try
        cnn.Open()
        MsgBox("Connection Open ! ")
        cnn.Close()
    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox("Can not open connection ! ")
    End Try
 End Sub`
```

Comment: Essentially, you are asking for a tutorial for ADO.NET. There are a ton of these - these concepts remain the same since .NET 1.0 back in 2002. The same for loading connection strings from settings. Hint : go to your project's settings and check the "Settings" tab.

Comment: Check for example [How to: Save and Edit Connection Strings](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms171887.aspx) in MSDN, the [ADO.Net](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h43ks021(v=vs.110).aspx) section of the documentation or one of the Pluralsight courses available for free through [Visual Studio Dev Essentials](https://www.visualstudio.com/dev-essentials/)

Comment: Is there anything wrong in your coding? you tell us - does it function when you run it?

Comment: i did open a lot of tutorial related to it but non of them help to solve my problem. everytime i click the button, the message appear "can not open connection". is it because i set the wrong connection string?

Comment: You'll need to provide us the error message from the `Exception` object of your `Catch` statement. You can do this either by setting a break or with this: `MsgBox(ex.Message)`. Press Ctrl-C to copy the MsgBox text to the ClipBoard.

Comment: @InteXX ---------------------------
LMWPatch
---------------------------
Can not open connection ! 
---------------------------
OK   
---------------------------

Comment: That's the `MsgBox` text from your custom text. We need the `Exception.Message` text. Like this: `MsgBox(ex.Message)`.

Comment: the error displays "login failed for user 'abc'"

Comment: @warabino you read the tutorials to learn how something works, not to solve some unspecified problem. Start from the beginning. And verify the username/password. BTW *why* don't you use integrated authentication? Windows knows who you are and so does SQL Server. Perhaps you should look for SQL Servers tutorials too?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In case of Integrated Security you don't have to use username and password.

Comment: if i want to include both password and username, do i need to remove the integrated security?

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to connect with "sa" login or with a specific user? if you trying to login using "sa" login make sure that "sa" login is activated.

if you have already activated "sa" login or trying to login with your Own user name, just change the Integrated Security=true to "Integrated Security=SSPI"